# postgresql: how to define a JSONB column with default value

Tags: postgresql, json

I am unable to find in the documentation how to create
a `JSONB` column in PostgreSQL that has a `DEFAULT` value of 
an empty json document.

How the above can be stated in the `CREATE TABLE` definition ?

Comment: what's an empty json document?  `""` contrains a string `{}` contains an object `null` contains a null ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

That's the same as with any other default value:

```
create table amsterdam
(
   id       integer primary key, 
   payload  jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb
);
```

Comment: How to set a default value other than `{}` ? .e.g `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: How to define default value for `jsonb[]` ?

Answer (score 22):

If you are altering an already existing table, then the syntax is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_column JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb;
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing accepted answer?

Comment: The captain here! `alter` vs `create`